# Load images into multiple picture boxes using the same click event

Tags: vb.net, image

I have a form with a panel containing 4 picture boxes:

[image]

I have one Load Image button with the follow code to load an image into the picturebox:

```
        'Procedure to upload images through the button click

    'open Dialog box to load image

    ofd.FileName = Nothing

    'Show dialog box above all froms

    ofd.Multiselect = False
    ofd.Title = "Select Image to Upload"
    ofd.Filter = "Image Files |*.jpg*"
    ofd.ShowDialog()

    'Select file and place on picture box
    If Not ofd.FileName = Nothing Then
        picBox.ImageLocation = ofd.FileName

    End If

    'Show the button to delete image
    btn.Visible = True
```

The procedure works well when I only one box to fill, but now I have 4 and I don't want to create a button for each box.  My question is, how can I use the same procedure (or something similar) to load pictures into a box other than the first one.

They would need to be loaded in order. For example, click the button, load Top Left box, click again and load Top Right box. So if all 4 boxes have no images, then Top Left goes first, if Top Left has image then Top Right goes next and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

Set the OpenFileDialog's Multiselect property to True, and then do this in the OpenFileDialog1_FileOK event:

```
For x = 0 To OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Length - 1
    Dim Path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames(x)
    Select Case x
        Case 0
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(Path)
        Case 1
            PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(Path)
        Case 2
            PictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile(Path)
        Case 3
            PictureBox4.Image = Image.FromFile(Path)
    End Select
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
dim i as integer
dim file as string
file = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
 For Each file In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
   if i=0
picturebox1. ImageLocation=file
elseif i=1
   picturebox2. ImageLocation=file
elseif i=2
   picturebox3. ImageLocation=file
elseif i=3
   picturebox4. ImageLocation=file
     end if
i+=1   
Next
```

give the order of picture boxes as in order you want.

Comment: You've just defined `file` twice, and somehow you first set it to an Array of String, while the variable is only a String.

Comment: Just as a little note. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like below; just replace the names of the PictureBoxes in the Array called "PBs":

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ofd.Multiselect = False
    ofd.Title = "Select Image to Upload"
    ofd.Filter = "Image Files |*.jpg*"
    If ofd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim PBs() As PictureBox = {PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3, PictureBox4}
        Dim nextPB = PBs.Where(Function(x) IsNothing(x.Image)).FirstOrDefault
        If Not IsNothing(nextPB) Then
            nextPB.ImageLocation = ofd.FileName
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```